# how can I replace this repetitive code with a more efficient function?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, function, tic-tac-toe

I am currently building a Tictac toe game in python. I have completed the game and am now trying to make the code more efficient. for context on this question, my tic tac toe board is drawn using a dictionary and changing it with user inputs, like so:

```
spots = {1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3', 4: '4', 5: '5', 6: '6', 7: '7', 8: '8', 9: '9'}
```

I have a function to loop the game if user gives a certain input once the game is complete. that function looks like this:

```
def wants_to_play_again(spots):
    play_again = input('Do you wanna play again?\n Press (a) to continue... \n Press any other key to exit the game: ')
    if play_again == 'a':
        print('\n')
        return True
    else:
        print('\nSee you later! Thanks for playing')
        return False
```

later in the code of the game itself, I say that if the above function returns true, then I reset the board, it looks like this:

```
        if wants_to_play_again(spots) is True:
            spots = {1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3', 4: '4', 5: '5', 6: '6', 7: '7', 8: '8', 9: '9'}
            available_spots = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
            continue
        else:
            break
```

My issue is that I reuse this block of code ^ another time in the loop of the game, if the board returns a draw. my question is how can I condense this code so that I don't have to use 5 lines of code to reset the board and available_spots elements. Could I turn it into a function that I only have to write once? Is this possible? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're only repeating 2 lines of code.  You'll need all of the others even if you use a function.  So, it's not too much code to repeat.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for your response. I was just concerned because the sentiment I seem to see online is that you should always try to make your code more efficient by condensing reused code into functions

Answer (score 0):

```
def wants_to_play_again(spots):
    play_again = input('Do you wanna play again?\n Press (a) to continue... \n 
    Press any other key to exit the game: ')
    if play_again == 'a':
        spots = {1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3', 4: '4', 5: '5', 6: '6', 7: '7', 8: '8', 9: '9'}
        available_spots = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        return
    else:
        print('\nSee you later! Thanks for playing')
        return False
```